# Why is Set-Cookie not showing in my response header?

Tags: asp.net, security

Im using aspnet. The configuration requireSSL=true is already in my webconfig.

Im quite new to this security thing and I dont know what went wrong. And what specifically i should look for.

Answer (score 0):

The **Set-Cookie** has to be there you have to carefully check the Server Responses. Probably it has already been set in another request and thus the **Set-Cookie** response header wasn't included. 
Moreover the **requireSSL** is about transmitting the cookies through **SSL** channel so if an **MITM** happens the attacker can't read the cookies in plain text.